# Execute code Before and After each Thread with Specflow in Specflow+ runner and SharedAppDomain thread isolation

Tags: specflow, specrun

Is there any way to execute code before and after each specific thread when executing tests in parallel with SharedAppDomain thread isolation in Specflow?

I was using BeforeTestRun/AfterTestRun Hooks for this purpose, but it seems that since last Specflow versions this is only possible when running tests "AppDomain" thread isolation, and in SharedAppDomain isolation it runs only once per test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your tests in parallel, each thread will represent a running scenario. To run something after each scenario you can use the `AfterScenario` hook.

BeforeTestRun/AfterTestRun are for the entire test run where multiple threads may be running. They are designed to run once for all threads but I have found `AfterTestRun` to be patchy. Sometimes it appears unable to determine that the last running thread has finished before entering `AfterTestRun`.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to run some code on each thread, at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: What code do you want to run, and how does that tie into the running of a specflow scenario?

Comment: One of the things I want to do is close the WebDriver. I have 1 driver running per thread in my tests.

Comment: Couldn't this be handled in an `AfterScenario` hook?

Comment: Could be, but then I would need to open a new WebDriver on the next feature, and do a new login, and thats what I want to avoid. I just need to open a webDriver and do a single login per thread, and close that webdriver when the test are finished.
I could manage this easily when [BeforeTestRun] was executed once per thread, but as this is not the case anymore since last updates, I was just looking for another easy solution instead of having to implement a mechanism to store all open instances and close them at the end of the test